# Will instance variable reset when I visit different action in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I think `@user` is an instance variable, which should be set after I visit the `localhost://users/1`, now if I navigate to `localhost://users/new`, why `@user` is nil?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # normally you would create a new model and assign it to the instance variable,
    # but if I comment it out, why is it nil instead of keeping the value from show action?
    # @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: give us the code, which you are using. need to show this class and the lines using this class, the statement printing nil.

Comment: I think the `@user` variable is a for the `User` model. do you have a model `User`. is yes. check the table and conform there are values in table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instance variables only "live" for the span of the request. A new instance of the controller class is created during each request. So if you visit the show page an instance of your controller is created with the show method called. When you visit new the current controller is destroyed and a new controller is created and the new method is called.

Comment: Really?? Is there any doc for that?

Comment: If you want to access a variable through the controller you can try class variable. Here is the documentation of class and instance variable http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html

Comment: I would suggest against class variables. They are not thread safe and seem like a rails anti-pattern since rails seems to be headed towards embracing threads.

Comment: @AZ http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html "As an example, if a user goes to /clients/new in your application to add a new client, Rails will create an instance of ClientsController and run the new method."

Answer (score 0):

An instance variable has a name beginning with @, and its scope is confined to whatever object self refers to. Two different objects, even if they belong to the same class, are allowed to have different values for their instance variables. From outside the object, instance variables cannot be altered or even observed (i.e., ruby's instance variables are never public) except by whatever methods are explicitly provided by the programmer. As with globals, instance variables have the nil value until they are initialized.
For more detail see:
http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/